# Write immediatly on the console

Tags: prolog

I want to abort my program right after it writes something to the console, but "write" is not displaying the message immediatly.

```
write('The AI wins!'), abort.
```

This is the message I want to be shown.
I tried it with "print" and it stays the same. I also tried it with "flush_output" but it gives an error message, that says "stream 'The AI wins!'" does not exist!".

Is there a way to display the message immediatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flushing before of abort/0. I think  write/1 it's not flushing the output and it get lost by abort/0, that throws a specific exception for console interaction. Indeed

```
?- write('The AI wins!'), flush_output, abort.
The AI wins!
% Execution Aborted
```

Comment: This is what I looked for. I missused flush_ouput. Thank you very much.

Comment: No need to call `flush_output/0` if you write a new line. E.g. `write('The AI wins!\n'), abort`.

Comment: @PauloMoura: that was my first tought also. I was suggesting write(...), nl or writeln. But seems nicer to stay into OP's search results... then I haven't debugged the first option. Good to know anyway.